# Token expiration asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using method below for taking token from asp net server.

```
public async static Task<bool> GetToken(string username, string password)
{
    var token = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
    });
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(ServerTokenString, token);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tokens = content.Split('"');
            AccessToken = tokens[3];
            TokenType = tokens[7];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then i save Token and token type in strings.
Then i use this token for making my requests. 
But what if token will expire? I need to resend username and password? Or there is easier way if client is already log in and his token has expired?

Comment: as I understand it you don't need a cancellation token because you are using await.  The token only matters if you are using the async functionality.  Since you have await it will never matter.  Even tho you call it "token" you have two string parameters -- that should not include a token -- just a URL and a string to send.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If token will expire after one hour, do i need to run my method again? Or there is more asy way to update my expired token?

Comment: It is not a token.  Just because you name the variable token does not make it a token.

Comment: Thank you Hogan for your help, but you didn't answer any of my questions

Comment: I did.  Did you read that link I posted?

Comment: Yes, but i still don't unserstand what you said,Just because you name the variable token does not make it a token. What is it then?

Comment: If you look at the documentation you will see what it is -- that is why the documentation exists -- to describe the API

Comment: OK I wrote a fuller answer to explain.

Comment: Are you talking about a Bearer Token used for authentication in your question? While @Hogan talks about a cancellation token for async tasks?

Comment: True, i was ask about bearer token not for task cancellation

Answer (score 0):

In C# a function can have multiple "flavors"  -- depending on the type and number of parameters sent it will it will call "with that flavor".  As we look at the documentation for `PostAsync` we can see the following "flavors". (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
PostAsync(Uri, HttpContent, CancellationToken)
```

> Send a POST request with a cancellation token as an asynchronous operation.

```
PostAsync(String, HttpContent, CancellationToken)
```

> Send a POST request with a cancellation token as an asynchronous operation.

```
PostAsync(String, HttpContent)
```

> Send a POST request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.

```
PostAsync(Uri, HttpContent)
```

> Send a POST request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.

If we look at these carefully we can see the first 2 have 3 parameters and the 3rd parameter in both is named "CancellationToken".  (You can read the rest of the documentation to find out what these do.)

The next two have 2 parameters with no token.

In your call you are passing to variables as below

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(ServerTokenString, token);
```

Since you are passing two parameters you will call the 3rd or 4th version in the list above.  That means they are not tokens -- (even with the "token" in the names).

---

You could change your code like this:
(adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
// Define the cancellation token.
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken CToken = source.Token;

var response = await client.PostAsync(ServerTokenString, token, CToken);
```

However, this would do no good.  Since you are using `await` the PostAsync will finish before there is ever a time to use a CancellationToken.

> *A CancellationToken is only used when the process is running on another thread -- using await waits for the thread to finish so you will **NEVER** need it.*